# dynamically select this.variable angular 12

Tags: typescript, angular12

I have problem with selecting variables predefined in component.
these are variables:

```
public editable1: number = 0;
public editable2: number = 0;
public editable3: number = 0;
public editable4: number = 0;
public editable5: number = 0;
```

next array of arrays:

```
public editors: []=[
['editable1', 'editable3', 'editable5'],
['editable1', 'editable2', 'editable3']
]
```

eventually i would like to increment variables according to lists provided in array

```
this.editors.forEach(element => {
  element.forEach(e => {
    this['e']++; // this suppose to be pointing to predefined variables, but it does not
  });
});
```

how can I solve it?

edit: provided suggestion is working perfectly, but i want to add additional information about syntax for more complex code.
i have changed variable, which have to be edited and now it is inside service.object.object.key:value
so it looks like this:

```
this.editors.forEach(element => {
      element.forEach(e => {
        (this.service.object as any)[e].key++; // this way I increment value of object, that is inside object, which is in service
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast your component as any, and then you can access its properties with ['prop_name'] sytnax:

```js
this.editors.forEach((element) => {
      element.forEach((e) => {
        (this as any)[e]++; 
      });
    });
```